# Multiplying intervals in Two's complement

Tags: binary-arithmetic, arithmetic, intervals

I want to perform some interval-operations, and for addition, subtraction, and logic-/shift-operators, that works very well.

The only problem I have is the multiplication.

An interval $[a, b]$ denotes all two's complement numbers $x$ with the property $a \leq x \leq b$.

An interval-operation means that if i have a binary operation $\circ$ and two intervals $[a, b]$ and $[c, d]$, then $[a, b] \circ [c, d] = [e, f]$ means that for for an arbitrary $x \in [a, b]$ and $y \in [c, d]$: $$x \circ y \in [e, f].$$

But additionally, I want to have the most precise or a very precise interval.

"The most precise" means that there are the values $w,x \in [a, b]$ and $y,z \in [c, d]$ for which holds that $w \circ y = e$ and $x \circ z = f$

An example of an interval-operation:

- $A = [7,14]$
- $B = [-6, 77]$
- $A + B = [1, 91]$

It's correct, because there is no value outside of $[1, 91]$ that can be reached, when adding numbers out of $A$ and $B$.

Also it's precise, because $7+(-6) = 1$ and $14+77 = 91$

It seems impossible to find an efficient algorithm that handles all the overflows correctly and finds the precise (or at least a good) interval.

Is there a good algorithm?

Comment: What are interval operations?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I added a definition and an example, does that help?

Comment: $7+(-6)=1$, not $-1$

Comment: What is the relevance of the numbers being represented using two's complement?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Because of the overflows it seems very hard to compute for example $[2146731546, 2146731854]*[-2144714992, -2144714893] = [-1474518098, 1600169696]$

Comment: In that case, what is the relevance of interval arithmetic? It seems that the question is only about multiplication of integers.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It is possible, that the for $[a, b]*[c, d]$, $b*d$ overflows $n$ times and $a*c$ overflows $n-1$ times, then, there is possibly a value $e \in [a, b]$ and $f \in [c, d]$ for which $e*f > b*d$ and $e*f > a*c$. This makes the problem highly non-trivial

Comment: @Odin It is actually impossible. The endpoints of the resulting interval are formed by multiplying appropriate endpoints of the original intervals.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus and why is it impossible then? There's no need to calculate the endpoints of the resulting interval this way.

Comment: @Odin It is impossible since the correct product interval is out of range.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Why do you think it's impossible? The sum interval can also be out of range, but it it indeed possible to implement the interval-addition efficient and 100% correct.
Also there is obviously a trivial solution to the problem (just use brute force), but i want the same thing efficient (logarithmic or constant time)

Comment: @Odin GMP implements multiplication of large numbers "in two's complement" efficiently. It's open source so you can check out the code. Or better, you can just use this library.

Answer (score 1):

If $0 \leq a,b,c,d$ then $[a,b] [c,d] = [ac,bd]$. The trouble begins when numbers can be negative. If $a,b<0$ then $[a,0][b,0]=[0,ab]$. If $a<0<b$ then $[a,0][0,b] = [ab,0]$. And so on. To consider intervals straddling $0$, partition them into their positive and negative parts.

Summarizing, I wouldn't say that it is "impossible" to find an algorithm for multiplying intervals, only that you have to consider numerous cases. Good luck.

Comment: You missed the problem. I know how to multiply intervals, but i don't know how to multiply twos complement intervals, especially the overflows.

Comment: So is your problem the following: "given $a,b$, compute $ab$"? If $ab$ overflows, then $ab$ is not a number in the range you consider, and the only thing you can do is resort to arbitrary-precision arithmetic. But then it's more of a programming problem, and there are libraries for that such as GMP.

Comment: I want to know, how the algorithm for that works, therefore I cannot use libraries. Also it is not easy, since I know no efficient algorithm to find the maximum, when the factors are in the middle of the interval due to overflows

Comment: Odin, I'm not sure what you mean by "efficient algorithm". These algorithms are very efficient. The libraries are open source (at least GMP), if you're worried about that. There is no overflow if you work in arbitrary-precision arithmetic, since it is handled by adding a new "limb" to the number.

Comment: The point is that I want to do it for Two's complement integers. It is absolutely useless for me to do it with arbitrary precision arithmetic because that is child's play.